# TypeORM how to do deep-relational queries with relations properties / property?

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

Atm I'm diving into **Nest.js using TypeORM and its query builder**.

I've discovered the **relations property** which can be used and I'm curious if it is possible to achieve the same result from the 2nd return statement in the snippet below by using the "relations syntax" in the first result statement.

It works for just one relation, but if I wanna combine more relations, I don't know how to do this.
I switched to try-hard mode and tried wrapping two objects like this: { ChildEntity_name, ParentEntity.ChildEntity_name }, since I could not spot this subject in the TypeORM docs, but (of course) it resulted in an error.

Any help and resource woulda be highly appreciated.

```
 async getAllDeep(): Promise<Order[]> {
    return this.orderRepository.find({
      relations: [
        'Orderposition',
        'Order.Orderposition,
      ],
    });

    return this.orderRepository
      .createQueryBuilder('order')
      .leftJoinAndSelect(
        'Order.Orderposition',
        'Orderposition',
      )
      .leftJoinAndSelect(
        'Orderposition.Article',
        'Article',
      )
      .leftJoinAndSelect(
        'Article.Supplier',
        'Supplier',
      )
      .getMany();
  }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do this. You need to pass `relations` as a nested object like this:

```
this.orderRepository.find({
  relations: {
    Orderposition: {
      Article: {
        Supplier: true
      }
    }
  },
});
```

This will result in this query:

```
SELECT * FROM "Order"
LEFT JOIN "Orderposition" ON "Orderposition"."order_id" = "Order"."id"
LEFT JOIN "Article" ON "Article"."Orderposition_id" = "Orderposition"."id"
LEFT JOIN "Supplier" ON "Supplier"."Article_id" = "Article"."id"
```